# Ember queryParams not updating URL

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to set queryParams in an Ember controller, but they don't seem to be updating the URL at all.

I have this abbreviated mixin being applied to the route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ControllerPaginationMixin from './controller-pagination';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
  setupController(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);

    controller.reopen(ControllerPaginationMixin);
  }
});
```

And here's the abbreviated controller mixin that is applied above:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
  sortKey: null,
  queryParams: ['sortKey'],
  actions: {
    sort(key) {
      this.set('sortKey', key);
  }
});
```

When I call the `sort` method from a component, I can see in the Ember Inspector that the `sortKey` property has been changed to the correct new value, but the URL remains unchanged. Am I missing something?

Comment: key is of String type?

Comment: Correct, ex: 'description'

Comment: Could you provide simple jsbin, please? http://emberjs.jsbin.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're trying to customize the controller class at the runtime.

You will reopen the controller every time a user visits the route, that's ridiculous.

Simply extend the controller definition with the mixin and you're good to go.

Comment: Ya. ^^ that. `export Default ControllerPaginationMixin.extend(...)` instead. But am I missing something in the 'abbreviation' here? What is the `setupController`, and `reopen` even _doing_ here? Seems like nothing. Not even inheriting.